# Kafka Consumer stuck joining cluster

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using Kafka with the Consumer API (v. 0.10.0.0). Kafka is running in Docker using the image from http://wurstmeister.github.io/kafka-docker/

Also I'm running this simple test:

```
@Test
  public void test2() {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    props.put("group.id", RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(8));
    props.put("auto.offset.reset.config", "earliest");
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

    KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
    Properties props1 = new Properties();
    props1.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");

    props1.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props1.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

    KafkaProducer<String, String> producer1 = new KafkaProducer<>(props1);
    KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = producer1;

    consumer.subscribe(asList(TEST_TOPIC));

    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(TEST_TOPIC, 0, "key", "value message"));
    producer.flush();


    boolean done = false;
    while (!done) {
      ConsumerRecords<String, String> msg = consumer.poll(1000);
      if (msg.count() > 0) {
        Iterator<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> msgIt = msg.iterator();
        while (msgIt.hasNext()) {
          ConsumerRecord<String, String> rec = msgIt.next();
          System.out.println(rec.value());
        }
        consumer.commitSync();
        done = true;
      }
    }

    consumer.close();
    producer.close();
  }
```

Topic name and consumer id are Randomly generated at each execution.

The behaviour is very erratic... Sometimes it will work, sometimes it will start looping when calling .poll() with the following repeating output:

```
2017-04-20 12:01:46 DEBUG NetworkClient:476 - Completed connection to node 1003
2017-04-20 12:01:46 DEBUG NetworkClient:640 - Sending metadata request {topics=[ByjSIH]} to node 1003
2017-04-20 12:01:46 DEBUG Metadata:180 - Updated cluster metadata version 3 to Cluster(nodes = [192.168.100.80:9092 (id: 1003 rack: null)], partitions = [Partition(topic = ByjSIH, partition = 0, leader = 1003, replicas = [1003,], isr = [1003,]])
2017-04-20 12:01:46 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:476 - Sending coordinator request for group RHAdpuiv to broker 192.168.100.80:9092 (id: 1003 rack: null)
2017-04-20 12:01:46 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:489 - Received group coordinator response ClientResponse(receivedTimeMs=1492686106738, disconnected=false, request=ClientRequest(expectResponse=true, callback=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler@2bea5ab4, request=RequestSend(header={api_key=10,api_version=0,correlation_id=3,client_id=consumer-1}, body={group_id=RHAdpuiv}), createdTimeMs=1492686106738, sendTimeMs=1492686106738), responseBody={error_code=15,coordinator={node_id=-1,host=,port=-1}})
2017-04-20 12:01:46 DEBUG NetworkClient:640 - Sending metadata request {topics=[ByjSIH]} to node 1003
2017-04-20 12:01:46 DEBUG Metadata:180 - Updated cluster metadata version 4 to Cluster(nodes = [192.168.100.80:9092 (id: 1003 rack: null)], partitions = [Partition(topic = ByjSIH, partition = 0, leader = 1003, replicas = [1003,], isr = [1003,]])
2017-04-20 12:01:46 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:476 - Sending coordinator request for group RHAdpuiv to broker 192.168.100.80:9092 (id: 1003 rack: null)
2017-04-20 12:01:46 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:489 - Received group coordinator response ClientResponse(receivedTimeMs=1492686106840, disconnected=false, request=ClientRequest(expectResponse=true, callback=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler@3d8314f0, request=RequestSend(header={api_key=10,api_version=0,correlation_id=5,client_id=consumer-1}, body={group_id=RHAdpuiv}), createdTimeMs=1492686106839, sendTimeMs=1492686106839), responseBody={error_code=15,coordinator={node_id=-1,host=,port=-1}})
2017-04-20 12:01:46 DEBUG NetworkClient:640 - Sending metadata request {topics=[ByjSIH]} to node 1003
2017-04-20 12:01:46 DEBUG Metadata:180 - Updated cluster metadata version 5 to Cluster(nodes = [192.168.100.80:9092 (id: 1003 rack: null)], partitions = [Partition(topic = ByjSIH, partition = 0, leader = 1003, replicas = [1003,], isr = [1003,]])
2017-04-20 12:01:46 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:476 - Sending coordinator request for group RHAdpuiv to broker 192.168.100.80:9092 (id: 1003 rack: null)
2017-04-20 12:01:46 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:489 - Received group coordinator response ClientResponse(receivedTimeMs=1492686106941, disconnected=false, request=ClientRequest(expectResponse=true, callback=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler@2df32bf7, request=RequestSend(header={api_key=10,api_version=0,correlation_id=7,client_id=consumer-1}, body={group_id=RHAdpuiv}), createdTimeMs=1492686106940, sendTimeMs=1492686106940), responseBody={error_code=15,coordinator={node_id=-1,host=,port=-1}})
2017-04-20 12:01:47 DEBUG NetworkClient:640 - Sending metadata request {topics=[ByjSIH]} to node 1003
2017-04-20 12:01:47 DEBUG Metadata:180 - Updated cluster metadata version 6 to Cluster(nodes = [192.168.100.80:9092 (id: 1003 rack: null)], partitions = [Partition(topic = ByjSIH, partition = 0, leader = 1003, replicas = [1003,], isr = [1003,]])
2017-04-20 12:01:47 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:476 - Sending coordinator request for group RHAdpuiv to broker 192.168.100.80:9092 (id: 1003 rack: null)
2017-04-20 12:01:47 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:489 - Received group coordinator response ClientResponse(receivedTimeMs=1492686107042, disconnected=false, request=ClientRequest(expectResponse=true, callback=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler@530612ba, request=RequestSend(header={api_key=10,api_version=0,correlation_id=9,client_id=consumer-1}, body={group_id=RHAdpuiv}), createdTimeMs=1492686107041, sendTimeMs=1492686107041), responseBody={error_code=15,coordinator={node_id=-1,host=,port=-1}})
2017-04-20 12:01:47 DEBUG NetworkClient:640 - Sending metadata request {topics=[ByjSIH]} to node 1003
2017-04-20 12:01:47 DEBUG Metadata:180 - Updated cluster metadata version 7 to Cluster(nodes = [192.168.100.80:9092 (id: 1003 rack: null)], partitions = [Partition(topic = ByjSIH, partition = 0, leader = 1003, replicas = [1003,], isr = [1003,]])
2017-04-20 12:01:47 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:476 - Sending coordinator request for group RHAdpuiv to broker 192.168.100.80:9092 (id: 1003 rack: null)
2017-04-20 12:01:47 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:489 - Received group coordinator response ClientResponse(receivedTimeMs=1492686107144, disconnected=false, request=ClientRequest(expectResponse=true, callback=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler@2a40cd94, request=RequestSend(header={api_key=10,api_version=0,correlation_id=11,client_id=consumer-1}, body={group_id=RHAdpuiv}), createdTimeMs=1492686107144, sendTimeMs=1492686107144), responseBody={error_code=15,coordinator={node_id=-1,host=,port=-1}})
2017-04-20 12:01:47 DEBUG NetworkClient:640 - Sending metadata request {topics=[ByjSIH]} to node 1003
```

Does anyone know what's going on? It seems a fairly simple setup/test to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the reason myself. So I was running the consumer on a topic with 1 partition only. Then, I was just killing the process with the consumer, so no clean shutdown.

In this situation the broker will keep the spot for the consumer until the session expires. Trying to join with another consumer results in that error until the expiry.

To solve one can do:
- Change group Id
- Wait till session expiry
- Restart the broker (?)

If someone with more knowledge can explain better, please do